# Facebook Pixel Event for Signup form

Tags: facebook, pixel

I am using a Signup form on my website. So there are 2 pages, one page includes the "Form" Second page is "Thank you" page. But I got confused about "Pixel Standard Events" on Both pages. What "Standard Event" should I use for the page(with form) and for "thank you" page. I fund Facebook instruction is confusing for this http://prntscr.com/kpljkd

Comment: The form page itself should probably just be tracked as a simple page view. And whether successfully submitting that form constitutes more of a Lead or CompleteRegistration event in _your_ business logic, you need to specify ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].